# Failed to instantiate module myApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Facing the following error:-

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] 
    at Error (native)
    at

If i remove the content from function then I am not facing the issue but when I put it in the function legislator and try to call it I get the issue. Is there any way to solve it by keeping it in the function only. I kind of need to use it again and again.

The code can be found at:-

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anirbanmishra/congress.php/master/web_test

Comment: show the content of `dirPagination.js`

Comment: This is not how we ask questions o n stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a better understanding

Comment: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/blob/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js .  --->> Content of dirpagination.js

Comment: @Maximus Its the Angular JS dirpagination script just downloaded it from the net

Comment: @Anirban, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Maximus I am trying to call the function legislator on the click of link in anchor tag...this should call the function which has a ajax call to a php script. The php script returns data which I parse in the function and put in $scope variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated the module inside a function and called the function inside onclick.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<a href="#legislator" onclick="legislator()">

<script>
    function legislator() {
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
        ....

    }
</script>
```

That module instantiation part should be outside.

EDIT : For your second problem, `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` should not be passed as a dependency in module instantiation.

This [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview) might help you.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

should be replaced with

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Replacing this would still give you error about legislators.length not defined... That you need to look yourself, that's not related to angular, some issue with the http request you had made to `getData.php`.

Comment: getting following error now --->Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'listdata' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: any clue about the second problem??

Comment: Going through it... http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview might help...